# Calculating the proportion of x to y velocity given an angle

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry if the title is improperly stated, it was hard for me to come up with a title for this question.

I'm working on a program that lets the user set the initial angle for a ball to travel.

How this works is the user sets a velocity say, 10.
My xDelta is defaulted to 1 * velocity = 10
my yDelta is defaulted to 1 * velocity = 10
So the ball will move diagonally downwards to the right by default.

So if my xDelta is 0.4 and my yDelta is 0.6, then the ball will move faster downwards, than it will move to the right, thus giving a new angle of movement.

I want to allow the user to input an angle, say 20 degrees. So basically, I need to calculate the proportion of my xDelta to yDelta.

Any idea how I can approach this? I'm thinking it definitely has to do with trigonometry but I honestly have no clue...Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Would it help for you to know that the x- and y-components are proportional to the cosine and sine of the pertinent angle, respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to convert from Cartesian to Polar Coordinates by doing something like the following (implemented in Python-esque pseudocode):

```
def computeDeltas(velocity, degAngle):
    # Make sure to convert the angle from degrees to radians.
    radAngle = math.radians(degAngle)
    xDelta = velocity * math.cos(radAngle)
    yDelta = velocity * math.sin(radAngle)
    return (xDelta, yDelta)
```

Comment: You're the man, thanks! Perfect!